# Create DER encoded ASN.1 with pre-encoded DER parts in Rust

Tags: rust, openssl, asn.1

I want to DER encode the following ASN.1 structure in Rust:

```
issuerAndSubject ::= SEQUENCE {
    issuer     Name,
    subject    Name
}
```

The [`Name` structure is defined in RFC5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.4) and complex. I don't want to redefine this in Rust.

I already have an `issuer` and `subject` created in rust-openssl:

```rust
let issuer: &X509NameRef = get_issuer();
let subject: &X509NameRef = get_subject();
```

I can easily get the DER encoding for these objects:

```rust
let issuer_der = issuer.to_der().unwrap();
let subject_der = subject.to_der().unwrap();
```

but I need to insert them in a `SEQUENCE`. My preference would be to use Rust's asn1 crate, which allows for creating `SEQUENCE`s:

```rust
let ias_der = asn1::write(|w| {
        w.write_element(
            &asn1::SequenceWriter::new(&|w| {
                w.write_element(&issuer_der);   // I know, this doesn't work, but
                w.write_element(&subject_der);  // how do I do it?
        }));
    });
```

Is there a way to create a sequence with the DER-encoded data?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the dervice macro and use a simple structure:

```
#[derive(asn1::Asn1Read, asn1::Asn1Write, Debug)]
struct Signature {
    issuer: u64,
    subject: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let data = asn1::write_single(&Signature{issuer: 0, subject: 1});
    let sig: Signature = asn1::parse_single::<Signature>(data.as_slice()).unwrap();
    let data = asn1::write_single(&sig);
    eprintln!("{:?}", sig);
    eprintln!("{:?}", data);
}
```

Comment: `issuer` and `subject` are `openssl::x509::X509NameRef`s. I think, these cannot be derived.